# Powershell Foreach loop not looping through each directory

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach, directory

I'm working on a script that goes through each specific folder in the directory, sorts build_info* files by CreationTime, grabs the most recent one from each directory and assigns it to a unique variable. I have the sorting part working, but the problem is that my loop isn't going through each directory, it's just getting the results from the first and putting it into multiple unique variables.

So, this is what I want it to do:

```
servers01 most recent build_info*.txt file --> $servers01

servers02 most recent build_info*.txt file --> $servers02

servers03 most recent build_info*.txt file --> $servers03
```

But this is what it's actually doing:

```
servers01 most recent build_info*.txt file --> $servers01

servers01 most recent build_info*.txt file --> $servers02

servers01 most recent build_info*.txt file --> $servers03
```

Here's the code I have so far:

```
$Directory = dir D:\Files\servers* | ?{$_.PSISContainer};
$Version = @();
$count = 0;

foreach ($d in $Directory) {
    $count++
    $Version = Select-String -Path D:\Files\servers*\build_info*.txt -Pattern "Version: " | Sort-Object CreationTime | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line -Last 1;
    New-Variable -Name "servers0$count" -Value $Version -Force
}
```

What do I need to change in order to make sure the loop goes through each path and assigns that path's file to its respective variable?

Comment: Just in case you missed it, I suggested a solution to your problem in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49632870/powershell-sorting-and-selecting-files-in-foreach-loop/49636032#49636032)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looping over the number of directories, but you're not actually looping over the directories as the variable `$d` is not used in the loop.

Try this, with added `Write-Host` so you get some feedback.

```
$Directory = dir D:\Files\servers* | ?{$_.PSISContainer};
$Version = @();
$count = 0;

foreach ($d in $Directory) {
    $count++
    Write-Host "Working on directory $($d.FullName)..."

    $latestFile = Get-ChildItem -Path "$($d.FullName)\build_info*.txt" | Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1      
    $Version    = Select-String -Path $latestFile.FullName -Pattern "Version: " | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line -Last 1;

    New-Variable -Name "servers0$count" -Value $Version -Force

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the looping problem! I do have another problem, though--for some reason, the sort is no longer working now. If I run it with your correction (which doesn't even touch the sort part of it), it gives me the second most recent file. I've tried changing the sort to descending and picking -First 1 and then -Index 0, but neither worked. I double checked the file properties for it and the most recent file, and it is in fact the second most recent (about a month older than the most recent).

Comment: @JeremiahWilliams It's odd that it changes.  I don't believe the sort was working in your original code as `Select-String` doesn't return an object with a `CreationTime` property. You can test this by running `Select-String -Path D:\Files\servers*\build_info*.txt -Pattern "Version: " | Get-Member`. See edit for solution that gets the latest file first, then sends this to `Select-String`.

Comment: Great, thank you so much for your help. That works perfectly.